# Comparing managedObjectContexts

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two persistent stores(both of them are sqlite store) and hence hence two **persistent** store coordinators and each of the coordinators works with a **managedObjectContext** of their own. Now, I have a situation here. One of my view observes for a notification of **NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification**. It receives the notification fine but  how do I compare which context triggered the notification.

I did the following to see if it is one or other of two contexts;

```
-(void)contextSaved:(NSNotification*)notification{
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = notification.object;
   if(context == myFirstContext){
     NSLog(@"This is the first context");
   }else{
     NSLog(@"This is the second context");
   }
}
```

Both of these condition fails and I do not get any kind of log but if I log the addresses of the objects, it seems fine like;

```
NSLog(@"Notification object pointer %p, first context pointer %@", context, myFirstContext);
```

How can I compare these two context to the context in notification and detect the saving context and act upon. Please do suggest. I would be really glad for any kind of help you provide.

Comment: How did you compile the code? -O0 right?

Comment: Is this method even being called. When you say both the conditions fail, it is strange, because you have an else condition, so one of them has to be called, whether correctly or wrong. Try to put an NSLog statement outside of the if/else block and see if it is printed. If not, you have not registered yourself as an observer to the contexts.

Comment: Sorry I used else if and I have log in both the cases but neither one is being called.

Comment: Nevermind, that wouldn't be the problem. Try to put a breakpoint into that method to see if it's called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly how you would check to see which managed object context posted the notification. The notification object is the MOC, and since you want to know if it's exactly the same object as some other known object, `==` is the right way to compare them. If neither `NSLog` produces any output, then this method is almost certainly not being called. Maybe you haven't registered for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` yet, or maybe you did register but with the wrong value for the `object` argument. Try setting a breakpoint on the first line of this method to see if it gets called. If not, look at where you registered for the notification and figure out why you're not getting it.

Comment: Do I need to pass the argument while notification. I used nil value for object while registering. My syntax goes like this;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];

Comment: However, even if I set nil to the object, while registering for the notification, I suppose framework adds context to the NSNotification object while posting the notification. So, I used the same context from notification. Is there something wrong with this. Infact what is the importance of object while registering for notification. If you could explain me briefly, I would really be glad. Does it mean that the notification on that object will only be triggered.

Comment: Yes, notifications only get posted if the `object` argument matches the posting object, or if that argument is `nil`. Have you set a breakpoint in this method to make sure it's being executed? If so, was it being executed?

Comment: Yes I forgot something. Thankyou very much for your help.